# Construct a PDA that recognizes the following language: L={uawb: u,w ∈ {a,b}*, |u|=|w|}

Tags: pushdown-automata

I am having trouble finding the PDA with 1 state for this one. So far my solution is this but i cant figure out how to get to 1 state. [image]

Alphabet:
{a, b},
Stack alphabet (the first symbol is the initial one):
$ S (this can be changed,i just wrote these 2),
Acceptance condition:
empty stack,
Deterministic (DPDA):
false

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can create a CFG for the language and then use [this explanation](https://www.javatpoint.com/automata-cfg-to-pda-conversion) on how to transform a CFG into a (1 state) PDA

Comment: Ah thats very useful, thanks a ton

Comment: happy to help :)